# 'to do something' vs. 'to be doing something'

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the usages of **to do something** and **to be doing something**. What's the difference between them?

Example:

To do something:
"This is a really big moment for us and for the team, **to finally announce** this game and finally begin to allow the community to connect with us and to grow around the game with us,” Bettner said.

To be doing something:
“This is a really big moment for us and for the team, **to finally be announcing** this game and finally begin to allow the community to connect with us and to grow around the game with us,” Bettner said.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. In this context, IMHO, I see little difference.

Comment: Are you familiar with what is sometimes called the "progressive aspect" and how it is used? If so, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: What's the problem? The progressive construction is grammatical with an infinitive, but it's optional, so they're both OK.

Comment: In your first sentence, I suggest you Insert the word "to" before "begin." In other words, "This is a really big moment for us and for the team, to finally announce this game and finally to begin to allow the community to connect with us . . .." While you're at it, you might as well undo the "split infinitive" and go with "finally to announce . . . and finally to begin to allow the community . . .." Also, do you really need the words "to begin"? Why not "finally to announce . . . and finally to allow the community . . .."

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in meaning.

To me, the second example implies that the person is speaking the sentence while they are announcing the game, while the first sentence might be spoken at any time.